# RCTFont.h file not found in react-native 0.60

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I am getting RCTFont.h file not found error after running react-native run-ios after upgrading to the react-native 0.60

Answer (score 0):

Try [manual linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios) vector icons package in Xcode and give read and write permissions to your project from finder and select apply to enclosed files

Comment: For latest react-native there is no . option to link the package manually. (Now using xcworkspace

Comment: In 0.60 you can link packages manually despite the auto linking, delete the vector icons from pod file and try manual linking in XCODE

Comment: So this can be seen below the libraries with .xcodeproj extension in xcworkspace